# My god, they've taken the ... that I've got to get to!

Tags: last-night-on-earth

There's a card ["I've got to get to the..."](http://flyingfrogwiki.com/ffpwiki/index.php?title=Card%3a%E2%80%9CI%E2%80%99ve_Got_to_Get_to_the...%E2%80%9C), which requires a player get to a building before searching again. There's another card ["My god, they've taken the..."](http://flyingfrogwiki.com/ffpwiki/index.php?title=Card%3a%22My_God,_They%27ve_Taken_the...%22) which takes over a building.

When a building is taken over, a player can't enter it.

What happens if a player needs to get to a building, but that building has been taken over? Can the player never search again, or does one of the effects go away?

Comment: I can't say I've ever played this game, but the names of the cards makes me really want to...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The card text says

> Play this card at the start of a Zombie Turn on any Hero and roll a
>   Random Building.
>
> That Hero may not search. Discard this card when the Hero moves into a
>   space of that building. If the Hero is already in the building or
>   cannot enter it, Re-roll.

Your scenario renders the hero unable to enter the building, so a re-roll is required.

This is [confirmed on a BGG thread](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/1971768) by an answer from the game designer:

> If the building is made unavailable to the Hero, then you must re-roll to determine a new building for the Hero to get to.

Comment: It didn't occur to me that the "or cannot enter it" bit would re-evaluate when the building's state changed. Thanks!